# Java: Help reading associative arrays in YAML using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

How can I read below in Java using Jackson?

```
innings:
  - 1st innings:
      team: England
      deliveries:
        - 0.1:
            batsman: ME Trescothick
            bowler: DT Johnston
            non_striker: EC Joyce
            runs:
              batsman: 0
              extras: 0
              total: 0
```

I have tried following class structures and none of them work:

Option 1:

```
public class Inning {
    public String team;
    public Map<String, Delivery> deliveries;
}
public Map<String,Inning> innings;
```

Option 2: 
I replace `Map<K,V>` with a `List<V>`

Option 1 gives:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (File); line: 30, column: 3] (through reference chain: cricket.CricSheet["innings"])
    at cricket.CricSheet.readFromFile(CricSheet.java:20)
CricSheet.java:20
    at cricket.App.main(App.java:12)
App.java:12
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (File); line: 30, column: 3] (through reference chain: cricket.CricSheet["innings"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
MismatchedInputException.java:63
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343)
DeserializationContext.java:1343
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1139)
DeserializationContext.java:1139
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1093)
DeserializationContext.java:1093
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromEmpty(StdDeserializer.java:600)
StdDeserializer.java:600
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:360)
MapDeserializer.java:360
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
MapDeserializer.java:29
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
FieldProperty.java:138
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
BeanDeserializer.java:288
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
BeanDeserializer.java:151
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
ObjectMapper.java:4013
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2902)
ObjectMapper.java:2902
    at cricket.CricSheet.readFromFile(CricSheet.java:18)
```

Option 2 gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "1st innings" (class cricket.Inning), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "deliveries", "team"])
 at [Source: (File); line: 31, column: 7] (through reference chain: cricket.CricSheet["innings"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->cricket.Inning["1st innings"])
    at cricket.CricSheet.readFromFile(CricSheet.java:20)
CricSheet.java:20
    at cricket.App.main(App.java:12)
App.java:12
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "1st innings" (class cricket.Inning), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "deliveries", "team"])
 at [Source: (File); line: 31, column: 7] (through reference chain: cricket.CricSheet["innings"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->cricket.Inning["1st innings"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:823)
DeserializationContext.java:823
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can better understand the YAML structure if you paste your YAML into an Online YAML Parser, e.g. https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

It shows:

> #### Output
>
> ```
> {
>   "innings": [
>     {
>       "1st innings": {
>         "deliveries": [
>           {
>             "0.1": {
>               "batsman": "ME Trescothick", 
>               "bowler": "DT Johnston", 
>               "runs": {
>                 "batsman": 0, 
>                 "total": 0, 
>                 "extras": 0
>               }, 
>               "non_striker": "EC Joyce"
>             }
>           }
>         ], 
>         "team": "England"
>       }
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

As you can see, the root is a `Map<String, List<Map<String, Inning>>>`, where

- Outer map has one entry with key `"innings"`, and value:

  - Array with one element:

    - Inner map has one entry with key `"1st innings"`, and value:

      - An `Inning` object

Since `Inning` has fields `team` and `deliveries`, that does map to the object starting at the third `{`.

So there are 2 strings outside that: `"innings"` and `"1st innings"`. Neither of your attempts allow for two names, so they cannot possibly work.

I'll leave it to you to decide if you want classes for that extra map. I'd suggest creating a `Game` class with an `innings` field being a `List<?>`. Whether that `?` is a `Map<String, Inning>` or some class with a `"1st innings"` field is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Note to self. Had to change to:

```
public List<Map<String,Inning>> innings;
```

and

```
public class Inning {
    public String team;
    public List<Map<String, Delivery>> deliveries;
}
```